# Can I analyze only .class files wih sonarqube?

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have some jar files that I'd like to run sonarqube scans (especially findbugs) against but I do not have the source. Is there any change to run the scans only against the class files?

When running sonar-scanner against the extracted jar file I always get a message like this:

> 18:49:58.364 DEBUG: 'freemarker/template/TemplateServletUtils.class' indexed with language 'null'

and when I define the language in sonar-project.properties as "java" I get

> 18:58:41.487 WARN: File '/home/hans/testcode/testproj/freemarker/template/SimpleHash.class' is ignored because it doesn't belong to the forced language 'java'

Thank you!

Comment: No, you can't. Sonarqube analyses **source code**, not code generated by a compiler. The latter may change/optimize some places so that a class file is no longer reflects the original .java code.

Comment: Ok now I'm confused - I thought that it is highly recommended to provide the class files to sonarqube as stated here: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Java+Plugin+and+Bytecode. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

SonarQube architecture is not intended to support this use case.

However, you can "trick" SonarQube. First, you can run CFR to have source files to show in SonarQube.
Second, in order to have bug reports, you can run SpotBugs manually and place the report at either `/target/findbugsXml.xml` or `/target/spotbugsXml.xml`. If a file is present, SpotBugs plugin will assume that analysis has already been done with Maven and loaded the issues from the XML.

What might break :
 - Some issue might be hard to map to their decompiled source file.
 - The line mapping will likely fail because the decompiler does not provide a 1 to 1 mapping.

**Alternative:**
Here is a Jenkins configuration example which combined a couple of tools including CFR and FSB:
https://github.com/GoSecure/jenkins-fsb